# Как на основе линейного однонаправленого списка сделать двусвязный с риверсией?

Tags: c++, списки

**Задание:**"*Написать функцию, создающую новый двунаправленный список на основе существующего однонаправленного, элементы в этом списке должны идти в обратном порядке*"

Написал код по созданию односвязного списка, как делать двусвязный тоже знаю, но как на основе одного сделать другой ,да еще с реверсией не пойму.

Надеюсь на чью-либо помощь

```
 #include<fstream>
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct Spisochek//создание структуры односвязного списочка
{
    int data; //поле с данными
    Spisochek*next; //указатель на след. элем)
};
Spisochek * Head = NULL;

void Add_elem(int a)//добовление в начало
{
    Spisochek*el = new Spisochek;
    el->data = a;
    el->next = Head;
    Head = el;
}

void show() //показать список
{
    Spisochek* p = Head;
    while (p)
    {
        cout << p->data;
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Peredel()
{

}

void del_tail() 
{
    Spisochek*ptail = Head;
    Head = ptail->next;
    ptail = 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Add_elem(i);
    }
    show();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct SpisochekDuplex
{
    int data; //поле с данными
    SpisochekDuplex * prev;
    SpisochekDuplex * next;
};
Spisochek * Head = NULL;
SpisochekDuplex * HeadDuplex = NULL;

// Заполняем однонаправленный список
......

// Заполняем двунаправленный список и делаем реверс
Spisochek * p = Head;
while (p) {
  SpisochekDuplex * pDuplex = new SpisochekDuplex;
  pDuplex->data = p->data;
  pDuplex->next = HeadDuplex;
  pDuplex->prev = null;
  HeadDuplex = pDuplex;
  p = p->next;
}
```